# I have some salvaged PNP transistors, should they conduct forwards past a particular voltage or are they damaged?

Tags: amplifier, pnp, damage

I have salvaged two A1490 transistors from an old amplifier. Both of them, if presented with a potential difference across the collector and emitter above about 13.5 V start conducting, even if there is no input at the base. Is this expected behaviour or are they damaged?

The datasheet I found is [here](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/savantic/1534.pdf).

Comment: What does the datasheet say? Add a link into your question.

Comment: @Transistor The link is there now.

Comment: Be much more specific 1) what can be expected of these transistors, read the datasheet 2) **HOW** do you apply the voltage? The Base-Emitter junction of NPNs and PNPs cannot handle large reverse voltages (often only a few volts). 3) if you didn't limit the current properly then you might have already damaged these PNPs. 4) Get a cheap **component tester** from China and these will tell you in a few seconds if your components is OK or not.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, make that 6 weeks and "a few seconds".

Comment: The datasheet says that with no base current that the device is rated at 120 V but with a collector current of 60 mA.

Comment: The voltage is applied with 0 V ground at the emitter and 13.5 V at the collector. The base is left floating so no current can flow into or out of it.

Comment: @JCollins That's an unusual polarity to apply. If you're assessing whether the transistor is suitable for some circuit, what exact property are you trying to measure? The reverse Vce voltage before breakdown?

Comment: _"The voltage is applied with 0 V ground at the emitter and 13.5 V at the collector." - is that +13.5 V (ie. positive on the Collector, negative on the Emitter)?

Comment: Has the terminology of collector and emitter swapped in the last 20 years? I've always known conventional current to flow from collector to emitter, thus the voltage bias is collector higher than emitter.

Comment: They are PNP transistors, so they work with negative voltage

Comment: @BruceAbbott No the negative (zero) is on the emitter. I'm trying to convince myself that these transistors should stay open circuit with no base current applied, yet they do above 13.5 V applied at the collector.

Comment: Are you getting confused a bit? PNP transistors are normally configured with the emitter at higher potential than the collector. NPNs are configured with the emitter at lower potential (as in the common emitter amplifier or open-collector NPN switch). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_output for example.

Comment: BVceo is normally lower than BVces.

Comment: @Transistor it appears I am..! Seems I'm less familiar with the PNP type transistor, it is strange to me that the collector and emitter designations aren't reversed in this case. In a similar way the MOSFET source and drain are counterintuitive for conventional current but make sense when considering electron flow. Ultimately when reversed, they have a behaviour more like what I would expect. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

If you apply +13V on the collector of a PNP transistor relative to the emitter, that will reverse-bias the B-E junction by about 12V (there is a diode drop in the forward biased C-B junction).

Vebo is rated at 6V Abs Max so you have exceeded the absolute maximum voltage and caused the E-B junction to break down.

If the exposure was brief and the current limited to a few mA, it should not have caused much damage. Higher current and longer exposure can destroy the transistor or, more insidiously, negatively impact hFE permanently (well, some of it can be recovered by annealing).

Answer (score 1):

PNP transistors work on opposite polarity to NPN transistors, so in normal operation the voltages on the Base and Collector are **negative** relative to the Emitter.  That is why in the datasheet the values for maximum  Collector-base voltage, Collector-emitter voltage, Collector current and Base current etc. are all negative.

The 'Emitter-base voltage' rating is also negative, but note that the connection order is Emitter to Base, not Base to Emitter. This indicates reverse bias, where the voltage between Base and Emitter is positive.

You applied a positive voltage from Collector to Emitter. Operation in this region is *not defined* in the datasheet. When the Collector to Emitter voltage is positive the Collector-Base junction is forward biased, dropping ~0.6 V. Therefore on +13.5 V the voltage between Base and Emitter could potentially reach ~12.9 V, exceeding the Emitter-base voltage rating of -6 V (= +6 V between Base and Emitter).

But why are you seeing conduction? In most bipolar transistors the Emitter-Base junction acts like a Zener diode with a breakdown voltage of ~7-8 V. However the exact voltage is not controlled or tested for because the transistor should not be operated in this region, and might be damaged or degraded if the current exceeds a few mA.

Bottom line is when testing a PNP transistor you should apply a **negative** voltage between the Collector and Emitter, which is the polarity it normally operates on.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple test in the first example, the transistor is in conduction mode. With \$\beta=50\$, the collector current should measure about 50 mA.

In the second schematic, the transistor should be off, so the ammeter will show almost 0.

The 100 ohms at R5 is probably not necessary, but if the EC junction has been broken, that R5 will prevent the power source and the ammeter from giving up their magic smoke.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTI0gM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for showing diagrams, which I think are more appropriate for answering this question.